# How to access component state inside withFormik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am having an input in my form which is for saving the `address`. Whenever address changes, I am storing it in a `state`.

I am using `Formik`. And making my component to support formik using `withFormik`. When I access values inside the `handleSubmit` i am getting values properly. But I am getting the value of the input as a string. It is correct because in input we are saving the address as a string. But I am saving `address` in `state` which is an `object`. How to access the `address` saving `state` inside `handleSubmit` of withformik.

Comment: Have a look over [this](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik)                                                                      
When your inner form component is a stateless functional component, you can use the displayName option to give the component a proper name so you can more easily find it in React DevTools. If specified, your wrapped form will show up as Formik(displayName).

Comment: How to access the state then?

Comment: Give [this](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik) a look.

Comment: Please add code to your question, to show exactly what you mean. Most importantly, all code involving `address`. Not clear to me what you mean when you say "I am saving address in state which is an object". Are you talking about the *initial value* of `address`?

Comment: Consider this [code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trivial-form-2b-formik-8guok). Observe that `data1` is passed in via "TheForm data={data1}". See how the `input` elements refer to "values.data.email" and "values.data.greet". Then in `onSubmit`, `values` is a parameter. In the alert, you'll see a JSON dump of the current values. I didn't use `withFormik` in that code, but does this help you figure out what to do?  If so, and you get it working, you can "Answer Your Own Question" below, with the code details. If this doesn't help, then add more code details to your question.